# AlarmManager.setExact is still inexact in Kitkat when phone sleeps

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm struggling with AlarmManager.setExact() for couple of days. My application needs exact alarms and works fine on older Androids with AlarmManager.setRepeating().

I've read that it has changed since API 19 and updated my code accordingly.

Here is the code responsible for setting an alarm:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), alarmOrder+1, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        getAlarmManager(context).setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTimeMillis, pi);
    }
    else {
        getAlarmManager(context).setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTimeMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
    }
```

Broadcast receiver starts new activity with alarm screen:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "AlarmTimeReceiver");
    wl.acquire();

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);
    alarmIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
    context.startActivity(alarmIntent);

    //Release the lock
    wl.release();
}
```

The thing is that while testing on Android 4.4 device connected via USB cable all works fine. Alarm starts on specified time all the time (with screen turned on/off). Unfortunately, when I disconnect device from computer, alarm starts correctly only when screen is turned on. When I turn screen off, alarms starts in inexact time.

Have I missed something? Have any of you experienced similar situation?

Comment: What is your `BroadcastReceiver` doing?

Comment: Starts an activity with alarm screen

Comment: Are you using a `WakeLock` to ensure that your activity gets a chance to start up?

Comment: Yes, see updated code above. It runs correctly on Android < 19. The problem starts with Kitkat so I assume it's sth with setExact.

Answer (score 6):

> It runs correctly on Android < 19

Not really.

A `_WAKEUP` alarm guarantees -- via a framework-managed `WakeLock` -- that the device will stay awake until `onReceive()` returns. Then, the framework releases the `WakeLock`, and the device can fall back asleep... if there are no other outstanding `WakeLocks`.

Your `WakeLock`, as written, is pointless. It merely duplicates the framework-managed `WakeLock` without adding value.

`startActivity()` is *asynchronous*. The activity will not be anywhere near started by the time `onReceive()` ends and the framework-managed `WakeLock` (and your additional one) are released. Now, *sometimes*, your activity will get a chance to start up anyway, because the device does not fall back asleep quickly. I presume that you are using `android:keepScreenOn` or the equivalent in the activity, so once you get to that point, there is another `WakeLock` outstanding, and the device cannot fall back asleep automatically.

However, sometimes the device will indeed fall back asleep before your activity starts up. *That* might have changed with Android 5.0 -- it would not surprise me in the least if Android is more aggressive about putting the device back to sleep more quickly. So, while your previous approach might have worked 90% of the time, it may be a lot less now. However, your previous approach *did not work 100% of the time*.

We see the same thing with services. In fact, this scenario is a lot more common there. That's why, back in April 2009, I created [the `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), and why in August 2013, Google [released `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html). Both offer a pattern for acquiring the `WakeLock` in `onReceive()` but then not releasing it until the service's work is finished.

Neither of those solutions will work out of the box for you, as both are tied inextricably to services. However, you can use those as a source of ideas for rolling your own. You need to move your `WakeLock` into a static data member (ick), and only `release()` it once your activity is far enough along that it has its own `WakeLock`. For example, if you are calling `setKeepScreenOn()` on a `View` in Java code, once that is done, I would expect that it is safe to release your original `WakeLock`. Then, the framework can take over and release the keep-screen-on `WakeLock` based upon user input.

Comment: You are right. That seems like a potential root cause of the problem. I focused on the setExact and completely forget about WakeLock. I'll have a look on it and will post results of my investigation soon. Thanks.